# Central limit theorem : relaxing assumption of all finite moments

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem, moments, truncated-distributions

Consider $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n b_{i,n} X_{i,n}$ where
$X_{i,n}$ are random variable neither independent neither identically distribution and $b_{i,n}$ are weights satisfying the Lindeberg condition. I managed to prove that if $E[|X_{i,n}|^s]< \infty$ for all integers $s$, then $S_n$ converges to a gaussian random variable $G$.

Now, I need to relax the assumption that all the moments exists. I read that this could be done by a sum of truncated random variables $Y_n$ and proving that

$$
\text { if } S_n \rightsquigarrow G \text { and } d\left(S_n, Y_n\right) \stackrel{\mathrm{P}}{\rightarrow} 0 \text {, then } Y_n \rightsquigarrow G \text {; }
$$

However, I have no idea on how to formulate the $Y_n$ to make this argument works. Has anyone ever heard of this technique?

Comment: This is standard, so asking whether anyone has heard of it is pointless.  Do you have a specific statistical question?

Comment: If anyone knows a good reference about this that could be helpful.